# Is there a low level graphic API/GPU API in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

On the web when you need access to a low level graphic API for performance or other reasons, you can reach out to WebGL, similarly there's OpenGL for android/windows and Metal for iOS.

Is there something similar in Flutter? Searching, all I could find was the [CustomPainter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html) API, which is not exactly what I was looking for.

The Flutter team has stated they're working on [custom shaders support](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30763), but that hasn't been released yet.

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/resources/faq#can-i-build-3d-opengl-apps-with-flutter

Comment: Thanks, but it's a bit different tho, what I want is not 3d, but some API to access a low level graphics API (interested in 2D). Basically being able to write code that runs on GPU (a shader would be ideal)